# PHPStorm Remote Host brows listing not display

Tags: php, macos, intellij-idea, phpstorm

I try to access remote host tree, but it does not listing anything! 
I add an image for better details. When I select a remote server it is not listing the the file. Also connect is correct for the remote host.

[image: Error]

Comment: 1) Try switching between Active and Passive FTP modes -- usually helps 2) If nothing -- collect detailed logs -- https://devnet.jetbrains.com/docs/DOC-1202

Comment: Thanks for your response 
Here is my log output:

2015-12-09 21:02:48,117 [ 277065]  DEBUG - ains.plugins.webDeployment.ftp - PORT 192,168,0,102,193,58 
2015-12-09 21:02:48,404 [ 277352]  DEBUG - ains.plugins.webDeployment.ftp - 500 I won't open a connection to 172.16.26.249 (only to 43.250.80.142) 
2015-12-09 21:02:48,406 [ 277354]  DEBUG - ains.plugins.webDeployment.ftp - PORT 192,168,0,102,193,59 
2015-12-09 21:02:48,697 [ 277645]  DEBUG - ains.plugins.webDeployment.ftp - 500 I won't open a connection to 172.16.26.249 (only to 43.250.80.142) 
 
 

Please help me 

Thanks

Comment: It just work When i turn the passive mode on ..

Thanks